# Lightweight java game library + IntelliJ = error org.lwjgl.openal.AL10.nalGenBuffers

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation, lwjgl

I am getting this error while testing the basics of OpenAl:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.openal.AL10.nalGenBuffers(IJ)V
```

In here:

```
IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
AL10.alGenBuffers(buffer);
```

I followed the steps to set up this library in IntelliJ, WindowsCreationTest can be done without errors

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure to follow instructions on how to set-up LWJGL with IntelliJ are described [here](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_IntelliJ_IDEA).

Here is a simplified explanation of what you need to do:

1. Go to File/Project Structure/Libraries
2. Add `lwjgl.jar` and `lwjgl_util.jar` libraries located in the `jar/` subfolder of your downloaded LWJGL distribution
3. Go to *Run/Debug configurations* and set the following VM option:

`-Djava.library.path=/path/to/lwjgl/native/<your platform>`

The `java.library.path` property must point to the directory where the native libraries for your platform are located.

The error org.lwjgl.openal.AL10.nalGenBuffers is solved calling Al.create before the lines mentioned:

```
AL.create();
```

Comment: thank yuou for your answer, but sadly I tried that before posting here it's not helping

Comment: I just retested this solution just to be sure under Windows and Linux and I was unable to reproduce the problem. But from your error it really looks like the native libs are not set up correctly. After you run the applications, please look at the Run tab in IDEA, there should be the command used to run the app (for example "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java" -Djava.library.path=C:\lwjgl\native\windows ...) and verify that the Java library path is the same as when you run it manually.

Comment: ok I updated my question, it is an issue with openal only (testing SingleStaticSource tutorial) http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=OpenAL_Tutorial_1_-_Single_Static_Source

Comment: OK, i did a bit of Googling and found this forum thread: http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=3216.0 (last post). After adding a call to AL.create(); before the code mentioned in you updated example I no longer get the error, can you verify that it works for you?

Comment: hej that's it thanks a lot! I wasted time troubleshooting for intellij connfiguration :/